# Is there an off-the-shelf translation dictionary for ISO 8859-1/windows-1252 codes characters into standard ASCII equivalents?

Tags: extended-ascii

I have a bunch of text documents (thousands) which have various unstated encodings. The majority are straight ascii, but some are windows-1252 or ISO 8859.

I would like to convert  the extended character set into some sensible standard ASCII equivalent, like for instance

```
{
   '\x93' : '"',        # Left smart quote
   '\x94' : '"',        # Right smart quote
   '\xbb' : '>>',       # Double greater than
   '\xbc' : '1/4',      # one quarter
   '\xbd' : '1/2',      # one half
   ...
}
```

Rather than building the entire dictionary myself, I'm wondering if there is already a sensible conversion list someone has made that I could just use and alter myself?